# I want to show a image only row 1 in my php table, but it image appears on row 1,2 and 3

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is a picture of my result in Google chrome

[image]

And here is my whole code

```
    <?php
    $tilkobling = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oppgave_normalisering");
    $sql = "SELECT person_table.personr, person_table.navn, person_table.adresse, 
                    person_table.mobilnr, person_table.postnr, person_table.bilde, 
                    mobil_table.model, sted_table.sted 
            FROM mobil_table, person_table, sted_table 
            WHERE person_table.personr = sted_table.stednr AND person_table.personr = mobil_table.modelnr";
    $datasett = $tilkobling->query($sql)
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="startside.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Per</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ola</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Arne</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<table >
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Nr<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Navn<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Adresse<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Postnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Sted</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Mobilnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Modell</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Bilde</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["personr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["navn"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["adresse"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["postnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["sted"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["mobilnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["model"]; ?></td>
                        <td><img src="per.jfif" alt="" style="height:100px; height:100px;"> <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the same picture of Per appears on Ola's row and Arne's row. Obviously i want Per's picture to only appear on his row and not the other rows. I tried a lot of suggestions from older post, but none of them have worked for me.

Comment: You should use inner joins instead of commas, what you are doing is a cross join and that is why the first are all the same.

Comment: @nbk The result would be the same with ANSI JOIN syntax. It will still cross product those two tables because there's no condition relating them.

Comment: But that doesn't seem actually seem to be the problem, because `person_table.personr` is different on each row.

Comment: no iz isn't he wirtes every time the same picture img src="per.jfif"

Comment: Have you tried joining tables? I think that's the standard way of getting data from different tables instead of using comma

Answer (score 4):

In your while loop, you have hard-coded `per.jfif` as the image source:

```
<td><img src="per.jfif" alt="" style="height:100px; height:100px;"> <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
```

Which causes all your rows to have the same image. Did you mean to use `$rad['bilde']` instead?

```
<td><img src="<?= $rad['bilde'] ?>" alt="" style="height:100px; height:100px;"> <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @Anis R. who solved my issue.

```
<td><img src="<?= $rad['bilde'] ?>" alt="" style="height:100px; height:100px;"> <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
```

Putting `<?= $rad['bilde'] ?>`  into the image src solved the problem. I linked a picture of the result below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnzZL.png